# Weird angle conditions in pentagon

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCDE$ be a regular pentagon and $M$ a point in its interior such that $∠MBA =∠MEA = 42^{\circ}$. Find $∠CMD$.

I have found by length bashing and ugly trigonometry that the answer is $30^{\circ}$ but I haven't found the intended synthetic solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
It looks like your calculation is a little off. I think the answer should be $60^\circ$.

It's best to see that using inverse argument. Let construct an equilateral triangle $\triangle CDM$ inside the pentagon. Then $$\angle MDE=\angle EDC -\angle MDC = 108^\circ-60^\circ = 48^\circ$$ and $\triangle DEM$ is isosceles at $D$. Thus $$\angle MED = \frac{180^\circ-\angle MDE}2 = 66^\circ.$$ 
It follows that $\angle AEM=42^\circ$ and similarly $\angle ABM=42^\circ$, which is our original point $M$.

Comment: The only problem is how to guess $60$ degrees in the first place. I did it with trigonometry bashing but how to do it properly?

Comment: This solution is not correct, since you need to prove by the both ways. Indeed it is $60^o$ but this solution is not complete.